# 期待通りの出力結果が得られないです。

Tags: c

C言語に慣れてないため、お知恵を貸して頂けると嬉しいです。

whiteとblackのいずれかを入力して、
whiteが2つになったら、pass
blackが3つになったら、failure
にするようにしたいです。
一応コードを書いてみましたが、
期待通りの出力結果が得られないです。

■入力例

```
4
black
black
white
black
```

■出力例

```
black
black
white
failure ←4回目にblackが入力され、その時点でblackが3つになったため、failureを出力する。
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int blackcount; 
int whitecount; 

void count_black(void) {
    if(blackcount == 3)
    {
        printf("failure"); 
    }
    else{
        printf("black");
    }

}

void count_white(void) {
    if(whitecount == 2)
    {
        printf("pass"); 
    }
    else{
        printf("white"); //strike!
    }
}

int main(void){

    int i,num;
    char Judgment[10];
    char *s1 = "black";

    scanf("%d",&num);

    if((3<=num)&&(num<=6)){
        for(i=1; i<=num; i++){

            scanf("%s", Judgment);

            if (strcmp(Judgment,s1) == 0)
            {
                count_black();
                blackcount++;
            }
            else{
                count_white();
                whitecount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

カウントしてから `count_black` `count_white` を実行することで、期待通りの出力が得られます。

この回答ではそれぞれの `count_` 内部での `white` 及び `black` の数を出力しています。

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int blackcount;
int whitecount;

void count_black(void) {
  if(blackcount == 3) {
    printf("failure\n");
  } else {
    printf("[%d]white [%d]black\n", whitecount, blackcount);
  }
}

void count_white(void) {
  if(whitecount == 2) {
    printf("pass\n");
  } else {
    printf("[%d]white [%d]black\n", whitecount, blackcount);
  }
}

int main(void){
  int i,num;
  char Judgment[10];

  scanf("%d",&num);

  if((3<=num)&&(num<=6)){
    for(i=1; i<=num; i++){

      scanf("%s", Judgment);

      if (strcmp(Judgment, "black") == 0) {
          blackcount++;
          count_black();
      } else{
        whitecount++;
        count_white();
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

また、回答とは外れるコメントとなりますが、 `blackcount` 及び `whitecount` をグローバルに置くならばそれぞれの関数の中でカウントするほうが分かりやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: PicoSushi様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
おかげさまで解決することができました。

Comment: @kumakuma この回答でよろしければ承認をお願いします。 [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) 以前の質問も同様に承認をお願いします。

Comment: @kumakuma　ご指摘ありがとうございます。